# How do cookie authentication on couchdb with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http, authentication, cookies, couchdb

Hey? Can someone hep me to do cookie authentication on CouchDB with AngularJS?

This my code:

```js
   var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){
  //Authentification cookie
  $http.({
    url: 'http://localhost:5984/_session',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data:{
      name: "packy",
      password: "packy8"
    }
  }).then(function(response){
     console.log(response.headers);
  });
}
```

The problem? i'm not able to read The AuthSesssion Cookie.

Comment: Please provide more information  for the script your are having trouble with the cookies

Comment: This is my code, please can you edit it?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are sent via HTTP headers. If you got a cookie in response you have to dig into the response headers.

Alternatively you can [ask the browser via JavaScript](http://mdn.io/cookie) to provide the cookie data that was stored automatically from the response into the browser session.

Answer (score 0):

To receive the AuthSession cookie from CouchDB you need to do a POST request to _session. The cookie you get is marked with a HttpOnly flag so it's tricky if not impossible to read it from the browser (at least I wasn't able to).

Once you have the cookie, GET requests to _session will return the logged in user, you don't need to do anything else. The one issue that I ran into was tricking the browser into prompting the "save password for this website" message, it seems they expect the POST request to be made from a standard HTML form not an ajax request. What I ended up with is a mix between sending a POST request using the Angular $http, then if successful do a full form request to _session as well as setting the "next" query param so I get returned to whatever page I need (otherwise you get stuck on the localhost:5984/_session page).